# Python script won't run on keyboard shortcut

Tags: python, linux, bash, keyboard-shortcuts, redhat

So i have plenty of scripts which i run from keyboard shortcuts, things like uploading screenshots to imgur and putting links in the clipboard, stuff for digitising plots, etc.

I have this current script, which only runs from the terminal, and not when i try to run it as a keyboard shortcut.

I'm trying to run it via the `System > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts` on `Scientific linux 6.4`.

I've included the script below, in case there's anything specific about it which would stop it from working.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import fileinput, os

import subprocess

from pygments import highlight
from pygments.lexers import get_lexer_by_name, guess_lexer
import pygments.formatters as formatters

#stdin = "\n".join([line for line in fileinput.input()])

p = subprocess.Popen(["xclip", "-selection", "primary", "-o"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
code, err = p.communicate()

if not err:

  lexer = guess_lexer(code)

  print lexer.name

  imageformatter = formatters.ImageFormatter(linenos=True, cssclass="source", font_name="Liberation Mono")
  formatter = formatters.HtmlFormatter(linenos=True, cssclass="source")

  HTMLresult = highlight(code, lexer, formatter)
  Jpgresult = highlight(code, lexer, imageformatter, outfile=open("syntax.png", "w"))

  with open("syntax.html", "w") as f:

    f.write("<html><head><style media='screen' type='text/css'>")
    f.write(formatters.HtmlFormatter().get_style_defs('.source'))
    f.write("</style></head><body>")
    f.write(HTMLresult)
    f.write("</body></html>")


#  os.system("pdflatex syntax.tex")

  os.system("firefox syntax.html")

  os.system("uploadImage.sh syntax.png")



else:
  print err
```

The way it works, is by extracting the clipboard selection using `xclip`, using `pygments` on the text, and then both creating an html document and opening it in firefox, and uploading an image to imgur (using another script i have, which i know 100% works), and then putting that image url back into the clipboard.

The `bin` folder it resides in is in my path.

I've tried all of:

```
script
script.sh (where this file is just a shell script which calls the python script)
/home/will/bin/script
/home/will/bin/script.sh
```

as the `command` in the `keyboard preferences`.

If i change the contents of these scripts to just something like `notify-send "hello"`, and that then produces the notification message, so i'm fairlyconfident it's a probelm with the script, and not the `keyboard shortcuts` menu.

Comment: I would place that `notify-send "hello"` to various places in the script to isolate exact line causing problems. Then you can move on. Maybe some part of your script needs some environlent you do not have when script is called via keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Another important thing would be to try to capture output of your script. If you have wrapper `script.sh`, you can try to redirect stdout and stderr (and everithng else) to file via something like `/home/will/bin/problematic_script.py &>/tmp/script.log`. Maybe this will provide more clues?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into exactly the same issue. Here's how I fixed it:

First of all, I wrote a one-liner shell script that looked something like `python /home/user/Scripts/script.py` where "/home/user/Scripts/script.py" was the location of my Python. I placed this shell script in the executable path.

Next, when I went to make my shortcut, I didn't tell the computer to run the file. I told the computer to start a terminal and gave the shell script as an argument to that terminal. In my case, it looked something like:`xfce4-terminal -x ralia.sh`.

This works for me.

Comment: I'm not using that computer anymore, but if this really is a *solution* then it's a ridiculous one!

Comment: ridiculous? yes. does it work? yes.

I did find a better way to do it. You can cut out the shell script middleman and put `xfce4-terminal -x python /home/user/scripts/python_scripts.py` on the launcher line instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in "with open("syntax.html", "w") as f:".
When using keyboard shortcuts for the script, use full path of the files in the script.

Instead of:

```
with open("syntax.html", "w") as f:
```

Use:

```
with open("/home/user/my_script_folder/syntax.html", "w") as f:
```

Change all filenames in your script to full path and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar issue. The problem is that it is necessary to use full paths to make it work using keyboard shortcuts.

In my case, this did not work:

```
#!/bin/bash
python scrypt.py
```

However, this did work:

```
#!/bin/bash
python /home/user/bin/scrypt.py
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible issue is $PATH being different between your interactive shell and the environment of the daemon or program that handles keyboard shortcuts.

Try right after "import os":

```
open("/tmp/debug.txt", "w").write(os.environ["PATH"])
```

Then run it with the keyboard shortcut and look at `/tmp/debug.txt`.

→ Try absolute paths for the binaries and if that doesn't help, consider jhutar's advice.

Comment: I have other scripts i run in exactly the same way in the same folder, and they work fine though.